# Show all data according to product_id in laravel-8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

This is my projects table. Can anyone help me? I am stuck on this for 2 day

I can show here datas of products table
[image]
You can see every product or app have unique id with button like if i click id 6 it will take me to next page where I can upload an excel file in project table. so things is like this App id:6 can have many projects data which can be upload form excel file. and every data of excel file have id

This is products table
[image]
This is where i can create products
[image]
If i click save and next i can upload excel file

This id projects table

[image]
You can see in my project table I can store data according to `product_id`. In my projects table I have three `product_id` 1, 2, 3. I want to show them according to `product_id`. For example, if I want to show data of `product_id` 2 then in my index.blade.php will show only data of `product_id` 2 not product_id 1 and 3

This is my `index()` method of projectController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $product = Product::with('projects')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->firstOrFail();
        $projects = $product->projects()->latest()->paginate(20);

        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
```

This is my `show()` method in my ProjectController.php

```
public function show(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
    }
```

This is user model user.php

```
 public function Products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');

    }

    public function Project(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project');
    }
```

This is product model product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'detail', 'image','color','logo','user_id'
    ];

    public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function Project(){
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
}
```

This is project model project.php

```
class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'chapter_name',
        'sub_section_name',
        'title_1',
        'description_1',
        'image_1',
        'image_2',
        'image_3',
        'title_2',
        'description_2',
        'title_3',
        'description_3',
        'video_1',
        'video_2',
        'video_3',
        'user_id',
        'product_id'
    ];

    public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function Product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

This is projectImport.php where i can upload execl

```
class ProjectsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        Project::where('product_id',Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id')->last())->delete();
    }
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Project([
            'chapter_name'     => $row['chapter_name'],
            'sub_section_name'    => $row['sub_section_name'],
            'title_1'    => $row['title_1'],
            'description_1'    => $row['description_1'],
            'image_1'    => $row['image_1'],
            'image_2'    => $row['image_2'],
            'image_3'    => $row['image_3'],
            'title_2'    => $row['title_2'],
            'description_2'    => $row['description_2'],
            'title_3'    => $row['title_3'],
            'description_3'    => $row['description_3'],
            'video_1'    => $row['video_1'],
            'video_2'    => $row['video_2'],
            'video_3'    => $row['video_3'],
            'user_id'    => auth()->user()->id,
            'product_id'    => Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id')->last()
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is my index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 8 CRUD </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse flex-column">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <a class="btn btn-success text-light mr-5" data-toggle="medel" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModel"
                    data-attr="{{ route ('projects.create')}}" title="upload project">
                        <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <form action="{{ route('importProject') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="d-flex">
                        @csrf
                        <input type='file' name="file">

                        <button class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: -60px" title="Import Project">
                            <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-2x"></i></button>

                            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ route('export') }}">Export User Data</a>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success text-light" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModal"
                    data-attr="{{ route('projects.create') }}" title="Create a project"> <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-lg table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">No</th>
                <th scope="col">Chapter Name</th>
                <th scope="col" >Sub-Section Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Title 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Description 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Image 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Image 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Image 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Title 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Description 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Title 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Description 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Video 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Video 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Video 3</th>

                <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($projects as $project)
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">{{ ++$i }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->chapter_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->sub_section_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->title_1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->description_1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->image_1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->image_2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->image_3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->title_2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->description_2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->title_3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->description_3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->video_1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->video_2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->video_3 }}</td>

                    <td>{{ date_format($project->created_at, 'jS M Y') }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('projects.destroy', $project->id) }}" method="POST">

                            <a data-toggle="modal" id="smallButton" data-target="#smallModal"
                                data-attr="{{ route('projects.show', $project->id) }}" title="show">
                                <i class="fas fa-eye text-success  fa-lg"></i>
                            </a>

                            <a class="text-secondary" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModal"
                                data-attr="{{ route('projects.edit', $project->id) }}">
                                <i class="fas fa-edit text-gray-300"></i>
                            </a>
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')

                            <button type="submit" title="delete" style="border: none; background-color:transparent;">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg text-danger"></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    {!! $projects->links() !!}


    <!-- small modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="smallModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="smallBody">
                    <div>
                        <!-- the result to be displayed apply here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- medium modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="mediumModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mediumModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="mediumBody">
                    <div>
                        <!-- the result to be displayed apply here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        // display a modal (small modal)
        $(document).on('click', '#smallButton', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let href = $(this).attr('data-attr');
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                // return the result
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#smallModal').modal("show");
                    $('#smallBody').html(result).show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                error: function(jq
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the whole model instead of the `id` column

```
public function index()
    {
        $product = Project::whereIn('product_id',Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id')->toArray())->firstOrFail();
        $projects = Project::where('product_id',$product->id)->latest()->paginate(20);

        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
```

---

It'd be easier if you used [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships):

```php
class Project extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
    }
}
```

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project');
    }
}
```

And access it like this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $product = Product::with('projects')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->firstOrFail();
        $projects = $product->projects()->latest()->paginate(20);

        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
```

---

**Update:**

```php
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::with('projects')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->firstOrFail();
        $projects = $products->map(function($product) {
            return $product->projects()->latest()->first();
        })->flatten();

        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
```

Comment: Dear Brother Its not working it only showing The first id data for every id. It should be show different data for every id . Like product_1 will show project_1 and project_2. And product_2 will show only project_3 and project_3

Comment: I added an alternative to my answer. Your queries looked a bit overcomplicated.

Comment: I have done the changes and updated my post but it have an error. The error is Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException
Call to undefined relationship [projects] on model [App\Models\Product].

Comment: Oh, you're using another syntax. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Brother: it`s still showing product_1 data for every product. like product_1 have project_1 and project_2. And also product_2 have same data project_1 and project_2

Comment: Because with `firstOrFail()` you only select one product. You also don't pass it to your view.

Comment: What change should i do in my view can you help me I am struggling with this its day 4

Comment: Use `get()` instead of `findOrFail()`. But then, you'll have to change the next line because it's multiple products now. So paging would be more complicated.

Comment: Using get() gives me this error: BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::projects does not exist.

Comment: Yep, in the next line - that's what I predicted. Do you really want to paginate the a relationship? You can do something like the following but I bet, it won't work with pagination: `$projects = $products->map(function($product) { return $product->projects()->latest(); })->flatten();`

Comment: Thanks you look its working. I don`t care about pagination. Now i have this error;-- ErrorException
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$chapter_name (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp\resources\views\projects\index.blade.php)

Comment: You're welcome. Just put a `->first()` after `latest()`.

Comment: Am I going right? I wrote this ````  $product = Product::with('projects')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
        $projects = $product->map(function($product) { return $product->projects()->latest()->first(); })->flatten();
````
But I have this error: BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp\resources\views\projects\index.blade.php)

Comment: The links probably come from the pagination. I would remove them.

Comment: Brother, I have removed the links. Update is Now its showing all product data. like product_1 have project_1 and project_2 . And product-2 have project_3. In my index its showing all data like project_1, project_2, and project_3. I was want it will show only product_1 or product_2 data will show

Comment: I see that you output `project` in your blade template but not `product` - am I missing something?

Comment: Still no products - am I still missing something? Are you sure, this is the right template since it appears to be a form and not the output?

Comment: No i have update everything. a user can have many product and products can have many project.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just don't understand your blade template.

Comment: Is if possible i can show data for specific app ID or product?

Comment: I was have same result using this: $projects = Project::whereIn('product_id',Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id')->toArray())->latest()->paginate(20);

Comment: sorry, You were right I have missed something to update. Now I have update projetctImport.php where i can upload excel fiel

Comment: sorry, You were right I have missed something to update. Now I have update projetctImport.php where i can upload excel fiel